# Series at $\infty$ of $\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm currently looking for the series expansion of $\ln(1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2})$ when n goes to $\infty$.
I've got this:

$$\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} + o\left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

but that's very ugly and wolframalpha gives me:

$$\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{2n^2}- \frac{2}{3n^3}+ \frac{1}{4n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$

How can i get the same result? I wanna get rid of that ugly little-o.

Thanks!

Comment: $\displaystyle\ln\left(1+\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}\right)=\ln\left(1-\frac1{n^3}\right)-\ln\left(1-\frac1n\right)$, and then use the well-known Taylor series for $\ln(1+x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that as $x \to 0$

$$\log(1+x)=x-\frac12x^2+\frac13 x^3-\frac14x^4+O(x^5)$$

that is by $x=\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\to 0$

$$\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)=$$
$$=\left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)-\frac12 \left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^2+\frac13 \left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^3-\frac14 \left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^4+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$

since

$$O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^5\right)=O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$

then expand keeping only the terms less than the fifth order.

Comment: Thanks ! I think that I understand certain points, but why it is O(1/n^5) and not O((1/n + 1/n^2)^5) ? (I think about O(x^5) and replace x by 1/n + 1/n^2 ?)

Comment: @SofianeDjerbi Good point! The fact is that $O((1/n+1/n^2)^5)=O(1/n^5)$.